# Unable to mount a partition on an SSD over USB

Tags: linux, mount

I'm trying to mount a 120GB SSD connected externally via USB to the new server. The SSD is full of data and I can't format it.

```
mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/sdd1
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

So

```
dmesg | tail
scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Crucial_ CT120M500SSD1         PQ: 0 ANSI:5
sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] 234441648 512-byte logical blocks: (120 GB/111 GiB)
sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
sdd: sdd1 sdd2
sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 11:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

I tried adding the drive to fstab

```
/dev/sdd1 /mnt/sdd1     ext3    defaults        0 0
```

Didn't work also I replaced it with UUID

```
UUID=ba1d4a62-0918-46bf-8664-21cb1b7bb263 /mnt/sdd1     ext3    defaults        0 0
```

I tried

```
mount -no remount,ro /dev/sdd1
mount: /mnt/sdd1 not mounted already, or bad option
```

None of them worked. I'm in need to mount the drive to retrieve all data from it.

Added command results.

```
#####file -s /dev/sdd*
/dev/sdd:  x86 boot sector; GRand Unified Bootloader, stage1 version 0x3, boot drive 0x80, 1st sector stage2 0x920c9d0, GRUB version 0.94; partition 1: ID=0x83, active, starthead 32, startsector 2048, 218089472 sectors; partition 2: ID=0x82, starthead 254, startsector 218091520, 16349184 sectors, code offset 0x48
/dev/sdd1: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data (needs journal recovery) (large files)
/dev/sdd2: Linux/i386 swap file (new style) 1 (4K pages) size 2043647 pages
```

Fdisk command

```
###fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008c809
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *           1       13576   109044736   83  Linux
/dev/sdd2           13576       14594     8174592   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Parted Command

```
Model: Crucial_ CT120M500SSD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system     Flags
1      1049kB  112GB  112GB   primary  ext3            boot
2      112GB   120GB  8371MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

Tune2fs Command

```
tune2fs -l /dev/sdd1
tune2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          ba1d4a62-0918-46bf-8664-21cb1b7bb263
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index
filetype needs_recovery sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              6815744
Block count:              27261184
Reserved block count:     1363059
Free blocks:              154680
Free inodes:              5319645
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1017
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
RAID stride:              1
Filesystem created:       Sun Aug 25 14:25:16 2013
Last mount time:          Mon May 18 07:54:51 2015
Last write time:          Sun Aug 25 14:28:29 2013
Mount count:              45
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Sun Aug 25 14:25:16 2013
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
First orphan inode:       1697155
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      033f8321-306b-4dd6-8bf5-f54db8940028
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

Comment: Have you created the mountpoint `/mnt/sdd1`?

Comment: @TimothyMartin yes sure I did but it's not accepting.

Comment: The disk format isn't one that `mount` can guess, so you'll need to specify it with the `-t` option. What does `fdisk -l /dev/sdd` show?

Comment: What does 'parted -l' show you?

Comment: @Claris  Model: Crucial_ CT120M500SSD1 (scsi)  
Disk /dev/sde: 120GB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B  
Partition Table: msdos  
  
Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system     Flags  
 1      1049kB  112GB  112GB   primary  ext3            boot  
 2      112GB   120GB  8371MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)

Comment: @JamesSneeringer  fdisk -l /dev/sdd

Disk /dev/sdd: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0008c809

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *           1       13576   109044736   83  Linux
/dev/sdd2           13576       14594     8174592   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: The output you posted shows the disk as being at sde1. Otherwise everything looks good.

Comment: @Claris the drive has changed its label automatically it was /dev/sdd and now /dev/sde.

Comment: These kernel messages are ok, they don't indicate any kind of problem. Please **edit** your question to post the output from fdisk and parted, it's unreadable in comments without line breaks.

Comment: Also, what is the output of `file -s /dev/sdd*` ?

Comment: @Gilles thanks for the comment, question edited and added all results

Comment: `needs journal recovery` in `file` output at least suggests a possible avenue. Maybe post the output of `tune2fs -l /dev/sdd1`. Is there a possibility that the underlying media is bad?

Comment: @TomHunt tune2fs results added to the question, kindly advice. Thank you!

Comment: Finally, try `fsck -n /dev/sdd1`. This will detect any problems. If there are problems post the output in your question before attempting to repair (with `-a` instead of `-n`). A "bad superblock" can be repaired easily enough. Other problems may require more delicate solutions.

Comment: @Otheus  fsck -n /dev/sdd1 >>>> fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2 >>>
e2fsck 1.41.12 (17-May-2010) >> Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check. >>> /dev/sdd1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.

Comment: OK, remove `-n` option. Check the http://serverfault.com/questions/493091/how-to-recover-data-from-a-corrupted-ext3-partition Q&A for additional help on this step.